# Boostrap - Accounting for different sized thumbnails in a single row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Most times when I'm using thumbnails the heights of the image are not uniform, as shown below:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  ...
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/360x270" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I have also created a simple jsFiddle showcasing the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/c49Tk/

So, how can I force all of my thumbnails to share the exact same height and change their width, ignoring and maintaining the aspect ratio?

Comment: You should save all your thumbnails in same size on server, what I mean: same aspect ratio + image size (resolution). All this just for thumbnails and then just call bootstrap to handle all the work (styling thumbnails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple answer to this one I'm afraid.

The way Bootstrap works, it assigns `max-width: 100%` to `img`.  In the example you're sharing, they are all being retained by their parent's width (span4).  In the same vein, the parents are getting their height from the image, so you can't even set the images to `min-height: 100%`.

If possible, you could resize these images server-side, although that's not exactly the answer you're looking for!

You could use JavaScript to force the heights of the images (although you would also need to force-remove the `max-width` property), but this would mean that you no-longer get the grid from Bootstrap that you're using.

I expect that with a little more JavaScript, you could:

- Set the parent (either the anchors or the lis) to `overflox-x:
  hidden`;
- force the images to all be the same height.

This will mean that all your images are equal-height, but you would loose the right-hand edge of any images that are wider..

One final option would be to simply force the image heights and widths via CSS, although that would also mean that you would loose the image aspect ratio.

One good piece of news though: as long as you use `class="row"` or `class="row-fluid"`, they will at least be cleared property, so if you have several rows of them you won't get nasty float-edge issues even if the images aren't equal-height.

Comment: I appreciate the detail of your answer, I had done some testing with the thumbnail CSS that confirmed a lot of the problems you described, and after your answer I better understand why. I've decided to resize the images server-side, and then display the same size image when using thumbnails. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @steve-gregory, glad to hear you were able to work it out!  If you have any questions in the future do feel free to open up another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS class to force it like

```
img { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
```